# Parse DateTime type in C# sent in JSON

Tags: java, android, .net, json, wcf

How do I parse Json date in java **{"UserCreationTime":"/Date(1348477516620+0530)/"}** this is json response i got from .net wcf service, it is basically DateType type in C#.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kippie Not an exact duplicate. That's C# and this is Java (even though C# is mentioned, I think the question is about how to parse a date on the client-side and C# is on the server)

Comment: @luiscubal My bad, must've misread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first number, `1348477516620` is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC.

The second number `+0530` is the UTC offset of the system that created this value, at this specific point in time.  But that number is *not* reflected in the first value in any way.

In other words, if all you care about is a specific instance in time, throw away the second part and just use the first part.

```java
Date date = new Date(1348477516620);
```

And yes, it's an ugly format and nobody likes it.  It's being slowly phased out in favor of ISO8601.